# How to find time delay between two time series data?

Tags: matlab, delay, cross-correlation

I want to know how to find delay between two time series, for example when we have this pseudo time series data:

```
A: 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1
B: 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1
C: 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1
```

For example:

```
A: 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 
B: 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1

clear all;
filename = 'pseudo.xls';
visi=xlsread(filename);  %nuskaitomi visi stulpeliai
[n,m]=size(visi);
A=visi(:,1);
B=visi(:,2);
C=visi(:,3);
A1=transpose(A);
B1=transpose(B);
C1=transpose(C);

t=(1:10);
plot(t,A1,'b'); hold on;
plot(t,B1,'m');

d1 = finddelay(B1,A1);
[c,lags] = xcorr(B1,A1);
d2 = -(lags(c == max(c)));
```

And the answer is d1=1 and d2=1. It all right.

But what about the time delay between B and C.

```
B: 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1
C: 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1
```

1. How to find two delay parameters?
2. And how it works when we have two long time series?
3. Perhaps you can offer and more methods of determining the time delay?

Thank you for your advice and answers :)

Comment: Why do you believe that there are two time delay parameters between `B` and `C`?  This answer is important if you want anyone (or me) to help you answer your question about determining time delays.

Comment: I a little bit hard to talk english, but I try explain. When I count the delay between B and C according to my above algorithm, the results is: d1 = 0 and d2 = 0. I think that this is wrong, because in the C data number 2 is first than 2 in the B. I think this is already a time delay. And other delays to be among another 2. 
If I have:
B: 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2
C: 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
I rather think that this is two time delays in the different time moments.
Or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Or maybe you know other method to find time delay? This is the most popular cross-correlation.

Comment: Perhaps what you may want to do is locate a portion of `B` and use this to search in `C` by cross-correlation.  It sounds like you are looking for localized changes rather than searching for similarity over the entire signals.  Why don't you try extracting out a neighbourhood of elements that surround the `2` in `B` and use cross correlation to search in `C`?

Comment: Would you please tell me the definition about time delay?

Comment: @YangZhang - Pretty simple.  Time delay is simply defined as the amount of displacement between one signal and an exact (or close) copy of the same signal that has been time shifted.  If the signals are not exact, then we assume that the signals have more or less the same frequency domain distribution.  The goal is to determine how much this displacement is.  For a more signal processing point of view, this is actually known as **phase** delay.  See this Wikipedia article for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_delay_and_phase_delay

Comment: Perhaps I intermingled between delay. Really, I analyze the clouds load machine (CPU) and my goal to set a time delay between the machines. And I think if one machine suddenly stops working and starts to work after some time, it is automatically placed second delay. Compared with the beginning of one of the machine before starting to work. Thanks for the comments.